# Background Bitmap image in Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-background

I'm currently working on a simple Android game for school, and the game runs for a little bit before it runs out of memory and crashes. I suspect this has to do with the number of images I'm using in the game (small, 10-20 KB sized files for 10+ items/characters/buttons, and also a very large, 450 KB PNG file for a splash screen background).

I've been using BitmapFactory to decode all of my small item PNGs, and I also was able to set the background for my main GameView as so (only the bare minimum of example code is included):

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private Bitmap background, invincibleBitmap;

//Sets the background bitmap to an image scaled to the same size as the user's screen
background = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background), getWidth(), getHeight(), false);
invincibleBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.invincible_item), 60, 60, false);
```

For the splash screen I mentioned earlier, however, I've been using the Activity's Layout XML file to set the image as so:

```
  android:background="@drawable/main"
```

I want to be able to scale main.png the same way that I did in a View in an Activity, hoping that it would help the memory overload problem. How would I go about doing this? I'm a beginner with Android in general so the simpler the solution, the better.

Comment: memory used by images has nothing to do with file size. it's related to the specs of image. widthxheight

Comment: You shouldn't do that with the splash screen. as a fast solution. copy and paste the main image to all the drawable folders. the same image in all folders. surprisingly you will see a different.

Comment: But, don't just do that. you should provide 4 images of that main image one for each screen resolution category (xx, x, l, m). that how you develop android application.

Comment: Which one worked? I will add it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To point out, image file size don't effect memory usage. It depend on the image specs: width x height x 1 byte.

You shouldn't set splash screen image in code by scaling it depending on screen resolution. The drawable folders are there to do that. Provide a different image with different specs for each of the screen resolution categories (l,m,x,xx,xxx).

> As a fast solution, copy and paste the ***same image*** to all the
>   drawable folders. Surprisingly you will notice a difference.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't accept it earlier since you'd commented it instead of answered it. Thank you again for your help!